# JSTL always posting null for Date with java

Tags: java, jstl

I have this `<form>` that is suppose to modify something.

When I send the `POST` request to my `Java` backend, everything sets up properly.

Only the `Date` in the class shows up as `null`

here is the var :

```java
class DummyComponentCalibration {
...
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endDate;
...
}
```

here is my controller function :

```
public String dummyModifyCalibration(@ModelAttribute("calibration") DummyComponentCalibration newCalibration, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
...
    System.out.println(newCalibration.getEndDate()); // always null
}
```

Every other function that doesn't return a `Date` is not null.

In my HTML, I use `JSTL`, I'm able to get the date from the `GET` function that is calling the page.

In my MYSQL, I use the `DATE` type.

This is the requestbody, you can see that `calibrationDate` and `endDate` is sent.
[image: Here is the post sent value]

This is in the java debugger, the `calibrationDate` and `endDate` is gone (null).
[image: Here is the result]

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: Post details as edits to your Question, and/or edits to your Tags, rather than as Comments.

Comment: JSTL does not post. Your browser does. There are debugging tools to see what your browser posts. Start first by checking if any value leaves your browser. If it does, very that the posted value is decoded to a Java date and time object.